# What Yoneda tells us about algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am currently learning about relative algebraic geometry, and I'm just trying to walk myself through some of the foundations and motivating examples before moving on to the proper stuff (symmetric monoidal categories et al.), starting with the category $\mathsf{Comm}_k$ of commutative $k$-algebras.
Below is my attempt at explaining the setup.

- Define $\mathsf{Aff}_k=\mathsf{Comm}_k^{\textrm{op}}$, the category of *affine schemes over $k$*;
- Define $\mathsf{Sp}_k=\mathsf{PShv}(\mathsf{Aff}_k)=\mathsf{Fun}(\mathsf{Aff}_k^{\textrm{op}},\mathsf{Set})$, the category of *$k$-spaces*;
- Yoneda's lemma tells us that,for $A\in\mathsf{Aff}_k^{\textrm{op}}$ and $F\in\mathsf{Sp}_k$,

  1. $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sp}_k}(Y_A,F)\cong F(A)$, where the isomorphism is given by the canonical restriction;
  2. the functor $Y_A$ is fully faithful;
- Define $\mathrm{Spec}=Y\colon\mathsf{Aff}_k\to\mathsf{Sp}_k$, the *spectrum functor*, as the Yoneda functor;
- Note that $\mathsf{Aff}_k$ is equivalent to the essential image of the Yoneda embedding (since $\mathrm{Spec}$ is fully faithful (by the above) and essentially surjective onto its essential image).

First of all, it'd be nice to know if all of the above is free of mistakes and the correct sort of approach, and if so (or even if not, I guess), here are my questions:

1. For the first fact that Yoneda's lemma tells us in the above, what exactly does the 'canonical restriction' look like in this scenario?
2. What does the first fact actually tell us about this whole setup? I've used the second fact, which is sort of a corollary of Yoneda's lemma, from what I can tell, but don't see what the first fact tells us.
3. Why do we care about the last bit, that $\mathsf{Aff}_k$ is equivalent to the essential image of the Yoneda embedding? I know that some places *define* $\mathsf{Aff}_k$ to be this essential image, and others don't...
4. If we work with a finitely-generated $k$-algebra $A$ then we can write 
   $$A=\frac{k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]}{(f_1,\ldots,f_m)}$$
   and then we have the bijection of sets *(if the category is small? see below)*
   $$\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)\longleftrightarrow\{y\in B^n\mid f_1(y)=\ldots=f_m(y)=0\}$$
   since a morphism is given by choosing a place to send the $x_i$, but since zero must be preserved, these images must satisfy the $f_i$.
   But are we working with small categories, and should we just be working with finitely-generated commutative $k$-algebras, or is this nice fact just a useful way of looking at the 'nice' objects of $\mathsf{Comm}_k$?

*I know there are a lot of questions, so if you only answer one, please make it 2 or 3 (but I think they are all reasonably linked).*

Comment: 4. Smallness is a non-issue.

Comment: @ZhenLin Why so? It sounds like it must be pretty obvious, but I'm just over cautious about things like this...

Comment: It is obvious if you know enough set theory to worry about these things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Yoneda lemma tells you that specifying an affine scheme $X$ is the same thing as specifying its "functor of points," namely the functor $X(-) : \text{CRing} \to \text{Set}$ it represents. For this observation to have real weight you should know examples of affine schemes which are most easily described by describing their functors of points.

For example, there is a functor $GL_n(-) : \text{CRing} \to \text{Grp}$ sending a commutative ring $R$ to the group $GL_n(R)$ of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $R$, and sending a morphism $R \to S$ of commutative rings to the obvious group homomorphism $GL_n(R) \to GL_n(S)$. The underlying set-valued functor of this group-valued functor is representable by an affine scheme (exercise), and the fact that it lifts to a group-valued functor means that this affine scheme is a group scheme, or equivalently that it is $\text{Spec}$ of a commutative Hopf algebra. But I don't have to write down this Hopf algebra to write down its functor of points.

At the level of morphisms, there is a natural transformation $\det : GL_n(-) \to GL_1(-)$ which, by the Yoneda lemma, comes from some morphism of Hopf algebras in the other direction. But again I don't have to write down this morphism of Hopf algebras to write down the effect it has on functors of points.

Comment: Note that getting group schemes this way needs one additional fact not mentioned in the question: the Yoneda embedding preserves products.  (Of course, this is not hard to show.)

Comment: IMO Grassmanians make a better examples, for in that case writing down the schemes is much more difficult!

Comment: @Mariano: unfortunately in that case I'm not familiar with how to write down the functor of points either :/ I guess it's something like f.g. projective submodules of $R^n$ of rank $k$? In any case, the OP's question is about the Yoneda lemma, which only tells us something about affine schemes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This is a brilliant answer, thank you! Will take some time now to read and work through it. Do you possibly have anything to say about questions 1 and 4 (even just a few words, so I can mark this as accepted)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've read through this answer and tried to follow it now, and must admit that I get a bit lost with your example. Actually, I must admit, I don't see how Yoneda (in the way it's phrased in my question) tells us that specifying $X$ is the same as specifying its functor of points? I see that $X(-)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sp}_k}(\mathrm{Spec}A,\mathrm{GL}_n)$, but this second thing is a collection of natural transformations...

Comment: It is sufficient to specify the functor of points of a scheme on the affine site, since the inclusion into the gros site induces an equivalence on Zariski toposes.

Comment: @Tim: specifying an affine scheme means specifying an object in the category of affine schemes. Yoneda tells you that this category can be identified with its image under the Yoneda embedding, so some full subcategory of the category of functors $\text{CRing} \to \text{Set}$. So I specified an affine scheme $GL_n$ for you above by specifying this functor (then claiming it's in the image of the Yoneda embedding, which I didn't prove, but this isn't hard).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ok, I think I understand a bit. So for showing that $\mathrm{GL}_n$ is in the (essential?) image of the Yoneda embedding $Y=\mathrm{Spec}$ we need to find some $B\in\mathsf{Aff}_k=\mathsf{Comm}_k^{\mathrm{op}}$ such that $\mathrm{Spec}B\cong\mathrm{GL}_n$. This means we need to find some natural isomorphism between these functors. That is, set isomorphisms $\eta_A$ between $\mathrm{Spec}B(A)$ and $\mathrm{GL}_n(A)$ for each $A\in\mathsf{Comm}_k$ that patch together to make a natural isomorphism?

Comment: @Tim: I don't know what you mean by $\text{Spec } B(A)$. You need to find a commutative ring $R$ and a natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(R, A) \cong GL_n(A)$ of functors $\text{CRing} \to \text{Set}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it looked odd to me as well, but from what I've written, $\mathrm{Spec}B\in\mathsf{Sp}_k=\mathsf{Fun}(\mathsf{Aff}_k^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathsf{Set})$, and so $\mathrm{Spec}B$ can be 'applied' to some commutative ring $A\in\mathsf{Aff}_k$...? And from what I wrote as well, isn't $GL_n$ the functor $\mathsf{Comm}_k\to\mathsf{Set}$, not $GL_n(A)$?

Comment: sorry for all the queries, I must admit, this is all a bit confusing to me on first read!

Comment: @Tim: ah, you intended $(\text{Spec } B)(A)$? I was confused because you wrote that $B$ was an affine scheme, not an algebra. In the second sentence above $A$ should be interpreted as a "variable" ranging over all algebras; I really did intend to name functors. You might prefer the notation $\text{Hom}(R, -) \cong GL_n(-)$, maybe. Anyway, if all of this is confusing to you then I suggest you slow down and learn some ordinary algebraic geometry before trying to plunge directly into the setting of symmetric monoidal categories...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In my setup in the question the category of affine schemes is *defined* as the (opposite) category of $k$-algebras. I have done a reasonable amount of algebraic geometry (two undergraduate courses) but have to dive into this symmetric monoidal setting rather speedily due to how my course works out sadly!

Comment: @Tim: okay, I see the notational issue. In standard usage, $\text{Spec}$, whatever its output, always takes as input a commutative ring; that is, it's always regarded as a contravariant functor out of $\text{CRing}$, and not as a covariant functor out of $\text{Aff}$. So when you write $\text{Spec } B$, $B$ should always name a commutative ring (as opposed to the corresponding affine scheme, even though these are in some sense the same thing).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I understand now! Yes, I do keep on forgetting that although opposite categories have the 'same' objects they are still in some sense different. Thank you.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is there any reason to use $\mathsf{CRing}$ over $\mathsf{Comm}_k$? Everywhere seems to use the former, but the notes I have use the latter...

Comment: @Tim: once you define the category of affine schemes, you can define affine $k$-schemes as the slice category over $\text{Spec } k$. So it doesn't make much of a difference in the end.